# I am getting an error when using the Null-conditional Operator: Syntax error, ':' expected

Tags: c#

I am trying to check null and I don't understand the errors shown. I have the syntax correct yet visual studio will not let me compile.

```
 if (customer?.Company?.Products != null)
```

These are the errors the compiler shows me.

> Error 259 Invalid expression term '.'
>   Error 260 Syntax error, ':' expected
>   Error 261 Invalid expression term '.'
>   Error 262 Syntax error, ':' expected
>   Error 263 Invalid expression term ')'
>   Error 264 ; expected
>   Error 265 ; expected

I now understand this is a newer shorter way to check nulls since Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I don't want a colon. I just want to check if any of the objects are null.

Comment: Oh... the elvis operator is there!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This syntax is new to C# 6.0 and Roslyn.

You cannot use it with older versions of the compiler.

Comment: Which version do I need to get?

Comment: You need to use version 6 of the _compiler_.  That's included with VS 2015.

Comment: Ohh, I am using Visual Studio 2013! I need to upgrade. Thank you!

Comment: That feeling when you open a VS2015 project in VS2013 and it takes errors like this to realize it. #Facepalm.

Comment: @SLaks this is kinda late, but I am using VS 2015 Enterprise with Update 3 and I'm still getting the same error. Any idea why ?

Comment: Weird thing is I had accidentally opened and run my 2013 project in 2017 where I used this operator, then switched back to 2013 and ran it and did a good amount of debugging without a problem! Only after I stopped it to make a change and tried to build did it start complaining.

Answer (score 5):

[Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) are supposed to be written in a similar to the following way:

`if (customer?.Company?.Products != null)`

Comment: Ok, sorry I have it backwards. I am fixing it.

Comment: Check the other answer then @Semaphore